# Execute external script upon save when in a certain mode?

Tags: hooks, saving, shell-command

When I'm in `org-mode`, I want Emacs to execute a bash script I wrote whenever I hit <kbd>C-x s</kbd> to save.  The script automatically syncs the file I am saving to my Raspberry Pi. It expects the file name as argument.

How do I tell Emacs to run the external script on `org` files when I save?

Comment: You can use `after-save-hook` to run the script

Comment: Is this our first immigrant? :-)

Comment: @Malabarba This is the second I have seen :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a simple setup that you can modify that allows you to sync `org` files to your Raspberry Pi, based on your bash script (untested, of course, because I have neither a Pi nor your script).  Modify the function with your script name.  It uses `shell-command-to-string` to put the command line output somewhere; you could also just use `shell-command` if that's not a concern.

You can then add it to `after-save-hook`, as @IqbalAnsari's comment suggested.

```
(defun sync-to-pi ()
  "Sync org file to Raspberry Pi with external script."
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (shell-command-to-string (format "your-script-name %s" buffer-file-name))))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'sync-to-pi)
```