# before-save-hook for cc-mode

Tags: hooks, cc-mode, advice

I want to customize `cc-mode` to execute a function before saving. One solution would be to modify `cc-mode` keymap to bind `C-x C-s` to a function which performs the work I need and then saves it.

My question is whether there is a hook I could customize for this? The [CC Hooks docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/CC-Hooks.html) don't mention a `before-save-hook` specifically for `cc-mode`. How should this be done through a hook?

Alternatively, how do I do this through `defadvice`? From reading the manual, the only way I could see was to enable the advice before saving and then disable after the work is done. This sounds cumbersome. What would be the idiomatic way of using `advice`s?

Comment: The function you add to `before-save-hook` can check the current major mode (e.g. `(eq major-mode ...)`) and *do nothing* if it does not match the mode you are customizing.

Comment: @Constantine Agreed. I wanted to check through if there is something more "built-in" for this kind of thing. IIRC `haskell-mode` has at least one of `after/before-save` hooks and I assumed this was standard practice for prog-modes.

Comment: @Constantine: could you convert your comment to an answer (expanding a little, of course)?

Comment: See [this thread](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/execute-external-script-upon-save-when-in-a-certain-mode/4115#4115) for an example use of *`after-save-hook`*; you can use the same sort of procedure but substitute `before-save-hook`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One fairly common way of restricting the action of a hook to a particular major mode is to check the value of `major-mode`.

For example, this hook prints a message before saving buffers using `c++-mode`:

```
(defun my-c++-mode-before-save-hook ()
  (when (eq major-mode 'c++-mode)
    (message "It's never too early to start saving (C++ code)!")))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'my-c++-mode-before-save-hook)
```

As a side note: sometimes it can be useful to check if a major mode is derived from CC Mode; we can do this by checking if `c-buffer-is-cc-mode` is not `nil`:

```
(defun my-cc-mode-before-save-hook ()
  (when c-buffer-is-cc-mode
    (message "Saving a buffer with a major-mode derived from CC Mode.")))
```

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, use a local hook:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (add-hook 'before-save-hook MY-HOOK-FUNC nil 'local)))
```

This adds `MY-HOOK-FUNC` to the **buffer-local** `before-save-hook` of each C++
Mode buffer, or any buffer in a mode derived of C++ Mode.

I find this more elegant that explicitly checking `major-mode`, and it has the
advantage that you can disable the `before-save-hook` **locally** for each
buffer with `M-: (remove-hook 'before-save-hook MY-HOOK-FUNC 'local)` without
affecting any other buffers.

Answer (score -1):

I once needed something like that for autocompiling my elisp files when saved, I used a approach like this (converted the approach to cc-mode):

```
(add-hook 'c-common-hook #'(lambda ()
                              (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'(lambda ()
                                                               (funcall #'YOUR-FUNC-HOOK)))))
```

Comment: First, did you mean `c-mode-common-hook`?  Second, it looks like it will add the function to `before-save-hook` the first time you enter a `C`-related language, but then that function will be called just before every save on every buffer.  What OP needs to do is run the function conditional on the buffer being in a specific mode (see @Constantine's comment for how).